# Add behaviour of css class into another class

Tags: html, css, less

How to apply behaviour of some classes into another, without changing html?
I want:

```
<table class="name">
```

to have behaviour like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">...
```

It is possible to achieve this with css?

UPDATE:

How to do this with preprocessors ( LESS / SASS )?

Comment: Look into using LESS or SASS preprocessors for CSS.

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery or javascript for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 ways to do this :

**Manually adding classes to every table using jQuery**

Using this method will mean you will see your site "flicker" the new classes once the javascript gets loaded (because CSS is less render blocking)

```
$('#name').addClass('table');
// or
$('table').addClass('table'); // Every table gets the class
```

**Using a CSS Preprocessor like LESS or SASS (this exemple uses LESS)**

```
#name { // Or table {
    .table(); //This is the bootstrap mixin for tables
}
```

Comment: Thank you,can i use CSS preprocesors with frameworks,like grails?

Comment: CSS Preprocessors are independent. You can use it with anything you like, and compile the final CSS file and use it in grails. LESS : http://lesscss.org/

Comment: can i add specified third party class to my class in less, without repeating myself by copying class code?

Comment: Of course, you can use what's called a 'Mixin' : http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature